# How to create external storagea when it doesn't exist?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

### Introduction

I want to add a external medium to a vagrant box,and it works fine. However when I shutdown the VM and run it again it tries to create the medium again so it throws an error because it already exists.

### Configuration

Here is the `Vagrantfile`:

```rb
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.hostmanager.enabled = true
  config.hostmanager.manage_host = true
  config.hostmanager.manage_guest = true
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/focal64"
  config.vm.box_version = "20211026.0.0"
  config.vm.box_check_update = false
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
  config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.10"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    disk_name = "secondary.vdi"
    controller_name = "sas_controller"
    vm_name = "mybox"
    vb.name = vm_name
    vb.cpus = 2
    vb.memory = 2048
    vb.customize [ "createmedium", "disk", "--filename", disk_name, "--format", "VDI", "--size", 2048 ]
    vb.customize [ "storagectl", vm_name, "--name", controller_name, "--add", "sas" ]
    vb.customize [ "storageattach", vm_name, "--storagectl", controller_name, "--port", "1", "--device", "0", "--type", "hdd", "--medium", disk_name ]
  end
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    apt-get update
    apt-get install -y apache2
    systemctl enable apache2
    mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sda
    mkdir /mnt/jaas-aisi2122-disk
    mount /dev/sda  /mnt/jaas-aisi2122-disk
  SHELL
end
```

### Steps to reproduce

- Run box with `vagrant up`
- Stop box with `vagrant halt`
- Run box again:

  ```
  A customization command failed:

  ["createmedium", "disk", "--filename", "secondary.vdi", "--format", "VDI", "--size", 2048]

  The following error was experienced:

  #<Vagrant::Errors::VBoxManageError: There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
  for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

  Command: ["createmedium", "disk", "--filename", "secondary.vdi", "--format", "VDI", "--size", "2048"]

  Stderr: 0%...
  Progress state: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR
  VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to create medium
  VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not create the medium storage unit 'C:\...\secondary.vdi'.
  VBoxManage.exe: error: VDI: cannot create image 'C:\...\secondary.vdi' (VERR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
  VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium
  VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleCreateMedium(struct HandlerArg *)" at line 510 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp
  >

  Please fix this customization and try again.
  ```

#### What I've tried:

Deleting the medium before creating it by adding:

```rb
vb.customize [ "closemedium", "disk", disk_name, "--delete" ]
```

Nevertheless it doesn't work, also thought of checking if it exists and create if not.

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to check if the file exists using ruby syntax:

```
if(!File.exists?(disk_name))
    vb.customize [ "createmedium", "disk", "--filename", disk_name, "--format", "VDI", "--size", 2048 ]
    vb.customize [ "storagectl", vm_name, "--name", controller_name, "--add", "sas" ]
    vb.customize [ "storageattach", vm_name, "--storagectl", controller_name, "--port", "1", "--device", "0", "--type", "hdd", "--medium", disk_name ]
end
```